# Windows store not allowing to download App

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I coded an app and uploaded to store after verifying with certification kit.
This app is for testing so I selected promo code option in store visibility

Now when I or some other user redeems code he see the app in his library but cannot download the app.

I published app three times and added notes to testers that we can't download it, but nothing changed.
This is the error

[image: Try again later, something happened at our end]

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes some time to propagate the update of app in servers, worked after some time

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, it might be related to the option of Distribution and visibility in Dashboard.

If your app is for Windows 8.1 and you choose the third one, you have to ensure that the account you login in the Store has been included by you in the gray box.

And the promotional code is a Windows 10 feature, so you're supposed to make sure that user should download your app on Windows 10 devices. If you choose the forth option, you still should download your app on Windows 10 device.

If the issue persists, you might have a try with the second option to see if your app could be downloaded normally.
[image]

Also, this exception can be related to the Store.
If you run your machine by Wi-Fi, you could try to make it connected with Ethernet. Sometimes wireless is protected with an encrypted VPN running from another country, which may block the Store.

Hope it helps.

Comment: App is with third option and all the condition written here are satisfied.

Comment: All other apps are downloading normally, Also tried by connecting with another network

Comment: Please double check if the Microsoft account has been added into the gray box and another option is to send email to reportapp@microsoft.com and wait for the feedback report about your app.